# com.google.appengine.repackaged may result in your app breaking without warning

Tags: json, google-app-engine, import

When i try to `import com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.json.JSONObject;` into my project it show an error **"Use of com.google.appengine.repackaged may result in your app breaking without warning"**. I try to use `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` but i got another error. **"SONObject cannot be resolved to a type"**. I also tried `import com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.util.Base64;` i get the same error as the first one. **"Use of com.google.appengine.repackaged may result in your app breaking without warning"**. Please help. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with the

> org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

JSON*.jar and some more jar files have locations changed now. You need to re-link them 
1. classpath
2. Java Build Path-> Libraries in Eclipse

Comment: i already linked commons-codec-1.6.jar with my project. Any other jar i missed?

Comment: Can you look into the jar files manually? Specifically org.json.JSONObject

Comment: Have you considered linking with the reference JSON implementation found in http://www.json.org/java/index.html ? Should solve the org.json.JSONObject error.

Comment: @S.P. I just upload the screen shot in question. As you can see i already added json-org.jar to my project but it still showing error

Comment: Problem lies with your linking of org.json.JSONObject

Comment: @S.P. the code i followed from http://code.google.com/chrome/webstore/docs/get_started.html

Comment: Have you followed the all the steps from Number 3 in Step 5 "Create Your App" ?

Comment: Yes. Once i did that all the jar file move to my project and i can see  the jar file in my eclipse.